# In Bootstrap modal, after clicking outside modal window, Window closes but the gray color is not going

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[Bootstrap modal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck5qV.png)
In Bootstrap modal, after clicking outside modal window, Window closes but the gray color is not going
[gray color Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhBsj.png)

Comment: Do you have any messages in console?

Comment: "Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later" I am getting this error only

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this script which will remove the backdrop from the window on close.
or put your modal out side any div but inside body tag only

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yourModalId").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
          $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        }).on("hide.bs.modal",function(){
          $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        });
      })
```

Comment: $("#yourModalId").("hidden.bs.modal",function(){ giving error here, what is the function?

Comment: i missed on, updated answer now...use the script now.

Comment: Error:- "TypeError: element.style is undefined" in Prototype.js